# HTTP POST to Azure webrole doesn't work from Android app

Tags: android, post, azure-web-roles

I have an Azure Webrole implemented with WCF REST service.
I am attempting to upload a small image file (less than 50KB) to this service with an HTTP POST request.

It works in the following methods:

1. Upload from a windows form application using `WebRequest`.
2. Upload from Android phone when passing through Fiddler proxy.

It fails with the same Android code on the same Android phone when trying to POST directly to the Azure Webrole.

In this case I get a timeout with the `SocketException` and detailMessage="Connection reset by peer".
When looking in the VM instance (using RDP) in Azure I see status 400 for this call.

Here is the Android code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
String requestStr = "http://servername.cloudapp.net/Rest/RestAPI?action_type=upload_file&user_id=5";

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestStr);
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

// Set the default connection timeout  
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for a connection.
int timeoutConnection = 60000; 
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeoutConnection);

// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)  
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data. 
int timeoutSocket = 60000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);

httpPost.setParams(httpParams);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-data-png");
httpPost.addHeader("FileName", fileName);

ByteArrayEntity byteArrayEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bytes);
httpPost.setEntity(byteArrayEntity);

//Execute HTTP Post Request  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Here is my WebRole code (that I use for testing this issue):

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "?action_type=upload_file&user_id={userID}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public void UploadFile(string userID, Stream fileContents)
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

Some more information:
I tried the same method but sent a short array of bytes like this and it did work:

```
String someString = "some string";
byte[] byteArray = someString.getBytes();
```

Which made me think that perhaps I am not reading the file correctly or maybe the byte array is too long (should 50KB be a problem?)

Here is the Android code I use to get the file's bytes:

```
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);
fileStream.read(bytes);
fileStream.close();
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I tried the exact same code in the Android emulator posting directly to the server and it worked... Why isn't this working from a phone?!

**UPDATE:** Turns out it was a weird problem with the WiFi on my router(!)

Everything else worked fine and only upload from an Android phone to Azure above a certain size failed... (Other uploads from the same phone did work...)
I changed my router to a new one and everything is working again.

Also: I would like to commend the Azure support person who did not abandon me for a whole week and helped me finally understand the problem.

I guess I should treat this as a freak accident and go on with my life :-)

It also means the code above is a good example of how to do things. Hope it will help someone...